# Promisifying Node SSH2 SFTP with Bluebird

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I am using https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2 for my FTP requirements. 
I tried below mentioned code:

```
'use strict';

global.Promise = require("bluebird");
global._ = require('lodash');

var Client = Promise.promisifyAll(require('ssh2').Client);
Promise.promisifyAll(Client.prototype);

var clientObject, conn;

function getClient() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (clientObject) resolve(clientObject);

        let authObj = {
            host: 'abc',
            port: 22,
            username: 'name',
            password: 'password'
        };

        conn = new Client();
        conn.connect(authObj);

        conn.on('ready', () => {
            conn.sftp((err, sftp) => {
                if (err) reject(err);
                clientObject = sftp;
                resolve(clientObject)
            });
        });

        conn.on('error', (err) => { reject(err) });
    });
}


function getList(){
    getClient().then((cObj)=>{
        cObj.readdir('.').then((list)=>{
            _.each(list, (file)=>{console.log(file.filename)});
        });
    });
}


getList();
```

Above is given errors as:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: cObj.readdir(...).then is not a function
.
.
.
/home/nk/test/node_modules/ssh2-streams/lib/sftp.js:1583
            cb(undefined, entries);
            ^

TypeError: cb is not a function
    at /home/nk/test/node_modules/ssh2-streams/lib/sftp.js:1583:13
```

From above error; it looks like it is pointing to this line https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2-streams/blob/master/lib/sftp.js#L1583

Is it possible to achieve ?

Comment: try `readdirAsync` ? When `promisifyAll`, bluebird will add an `Async` version for each method.

Comment: It is giving me an error as: `Unhandled rejection TypeError: cObj.readdirAsync is not a function`

Comment: @TuanAnhTran however; `console.log(cObj.readdir);` gives me `[Function]`; while `console.log(cObj.readdirAsync);` gives me `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [ssh2-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-promise) npm package for catering the same. I have promisified SSH2 and SFTP item. Hopefully, it will help